# Best alternative to using if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automata

I am trying to break out of a bad habit of using if/else too frequently. I am new to how functions work and the proper way to call them but I am constantly researching the correct way to implement them with my code. The code that I am making is suppose to check for 3 different words and if the word is not in the input then the user will receive a statement that says "rejected" if the word is correct it will say "accepted". The issue that I am facing is getting my program to work correctly. So far I have set up my program to check each index of the word and if it matches the full word it will be marked as accepted. I am trying to figure out the correct way to add a rejected flag and to avoid the error that I recieve after running this program.

```
def checker():
  q0 = input("enter word:")
  if (q0[0]) +(q0[1]) == "if":
    print ("accepted")
  if (q0[0]) + (q0[1]) + (q0[2]) + q0[3] == "else": 
    print("accepted")
  if(q0[0]) + (q0[1]) == "do":
    print("accepted")
  else:
    print("rejected")
checker()
```

For this program, I am not going to use a dictionary so I can correctly challenge myself and implement this in an automata fashion. How can I implement this code without getting the string index out of range error. I tried to put break after my print statement but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance to everyone. This is my first post so if I have made any mistakes in my post please let me know!

Comment: what's wrong with `if q0 == 'if':`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it works but it seems like the other if statements conflict it says accepted but right after it says  string index out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extensible one-liner for you:

```
def check():
    q = input().strip()
    acceptable = {'if', 'else', 'do'}
    print('accepted' if q in acceptable else 'rejected')
```

The variable `acceptable` is [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset); a data structure which is very quick to check if something is inside of it. You can modify this set (or pass it to `check` as an argument!) to change the range of acceptable words without changing the control flow of the program (as you would in your original if/else implementation that you're laudably trying to move away from).

EDIT: I guess it's not strictly a 'one-liner'...

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you access each character of the input string, then concatenate them again, then compare to a target string("if", "else", "do")?

Second, why do you use `if` statements repeatedly if matching either one of them will lead to the same result (`print("accepted")`?

Try this:

```py
def checker():
  q0 = input("enter word:")
  if q0 in ["if", "else", "do"]:
    print("accepted")
  else:
    print("rejected")
checker()
```

Now, you just compare a string `q0` to another (each element of the list ["if", "else", "do"]). Also, the first hit in the list will make stop comparing anymore and will continue on to print "accepted".

++ Just to let you know why are you seeing "index out of range error", you are accessing each character of `q0` without knowing how many there are. So if the user inputs a string like `a`, there's no `q0[1]` or `q0[2]`, but you're asking your program to access it. Thus index out of range error.

Comment: Thanks man. It sucks because the class I’m doing this for doesn’t want me to use an array or dictionary of any kind. I would set it up just like this if possible. I ended up creating a program that accepts input letter by letter and it will say if it’s correct or not. I wanted to try and create a program that takes the whole word but at this point it just looks out of my reach without a dictionary/array.

Comment: If you really want not to use a list (there is no array in python), you can keep your program but change each condition of `if` statements read something like `q0 == "if"`, `q0 == "else"` and so on. Also, consider using `if-elif-elif-else` sequence instead of `if-if-if-else`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop and one if statement if that is better for you. Simply put all the accepted values into a list and check if each word is in q0.

```
def checker():
    q0 = input('enter word:')
    for i in ['if', 'else', 'do']:
        result = ('accepted' if i in q0 else 'rejected')
        if result == 'accepted':
            break
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as one liner with lambda function.

```
checker = lambda q: print("accepted" if q in ["elif", "if", "else"] else "rejected")
checker()
```

here is a sample

```
>>> checker = lambda q: print("accepted" if q in ["elif", "if", "else"] else 
"rejected")
>>> checker("if")
accepted
>>> checker("fool")
rejected
```

Comment: Note that assigning lambda function to an identifier is considered harmful by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: Thanks, I know that lambda function assignment to a identifier is not recommended but I was just giving an example that it can be done this way.